# Recursively create file with random content with GNU find

Tags: bash, find, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My intention was to quickly create a directory tree like the following:

```
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- 01
|   |   `-- file_00
|   |       
|   |-- 02
|   |   `-- file_00
|   |       
|   |-- 03
|   |   `-- file_00
|   |       
|   |-- 04
|       `-- file_00
|           
`-- dir2
    |-- 01
    |   `-- file_00
    |       
    |-- 02
    |   `-- file_00
    |       
    |-- 03
    |   `-- file_00
    |      
    `-- 04
        `-- file_00
```

Which I accomplished by:

```
mkdir {dir1,dir2}
mkdir ./{dir1,dir2}/{01,02,03,04}
touch ./{dir1,dir2}/{01,02,03,04}/file_00
```

But when I wanted to append a random number, `$RANDOM` is random enough, to each `file_00` I ran into problems. I tried:

```
find . -type f -name 'file_00' -exec echo $RANDOM > {} \;
```

But that created a file named `{}`, on the working directory, with the same random number repeated as many times as `find` had a match (or so I assume).

**How could I write a random number to each `file_00`?**

---

`/dev/random` is available on WSL

Comment: Do you have a `/dev/random` device file?

Comment: Don't comment your question, but **edit your question** to improv it

Comment: The problem is that `$RANDOM` and  `> {}` are both parsed & applied by the shell *before* `find` even runs; that means that `find` just sees something like `-exec echo 13196 \;` in its argument list, and `find`'s output is redirected to a file named "{}". In order to get what you want, you need to defer them until later, and have them applied separately to each item `find` finds.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I get that `$RANDOM` is interpreted by the shell, but is `{}` not the placeholder for `find`'s matches?

Comment: `{}` *would* be a placeholder if `find` handled it, but the shell parses and removes it before `find` can even see it. Note that @glennjackman's solutions all involve some sort of second level of shell parsing: shell parses the find command (without computing `$RANDOM` or redirecting output) -> `find` finds a list of matching files and passes it to -> *another* shell construct (either a `bash -c` subshell or a `while` loop) that takes the filenames and does the `$RANDOM` and `> foundfile` separately for each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

small improvement, use `mkdir -p` and you only need the one mkdir command.

call out to a shell in the -exec directive:

```
find . -type f \
       -name file_00 \
       -exec bash -c 'for file; do echo $RANDOM > "$file"; done' bash '{}' +
```

or just iterate over the `find` results

```
find . -type f -name file_00 -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do 
    echo $RANDOM > "$filename"
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! :) Though I don't understand why it ends with `bash '{}' +`

Comment: I am using the `-exec` clause with the `+` form, which means find will put *multiple* filenames into `{}` (check the find man page). When you do `bash -c '...' arg1 arg2 arg3 ...`, bash takes the first argument as `$0`, the second argument as `$1`, and so on.  I use "bash" to put something into `$0` which we don't care about, then `for file; do ...` to iterate over $1, $2, ...